# How to display languages not supported by iPhone

Tags: iphone

How to display languages like hindi, sanskrit, etc in iPhone devices? These languages are not available in iPhone 3.0, so how to display them.

Comment: Where do you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems and also one of the plus points of the Iphone platform is the control that Apple exerts in ensuring that only it's desired ways of doing things are acceptable.

So if it is not supported then the only only way to do this would be to use some form of graphic library with the characters and possibly that you'd have write it yourself.